# Using a HashMap and reflection to call methods with variable argument types

Tags: java, reflection, types, variadic-functions

So, I have the following scenario:

- I have a class named `AIInstruction`, which is not actually meant to be instantiated by itself, but trough a child class.
- I have a bunch of classes called `AIInstruction_***` which extend `AIInstruction`. Every single one of these classes has a single constructor, but differ in the type and amount of parameters they need.
- And I have a manager class which looks something like this:

  ```
  public class AIControls
  {
      public static HashMap<String, Class<? extends AIInstruction>> INSTRUCTION_DICTIONARY = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends AIInstruction>>();
      static {
          INSTRUCTION_DICTIONARY.put("rotateTowards", AIInstruction_rotateTowards.class);
          INSTRUCTION_DICTIONARY.put("moveToPoint", AIInstruction_moveToPoint.class);
          // (etc...)
      }

      LinkedList<AIInstruction> _instruction_queue;

      public AIControls()
      {
          _instruction_queue = new LinkedList<AIInstruction>();
      }

      public void addInstruction(String instruction, Object... params)
      {
          /*
          ???
          */
      }
  }
  ```

What I want to do inside `addInstruction`, is creating an instance of the class whose key inside the `INSTRUCTION_DICTIONARY` is `instruction`, and add this new instance to the `_instruction_queue` LinkedList.
The `params` varargs are meant to be the parameters that the constructor method of the class reffered to by `instruction` needs.

From what I researched, I found that reflection is pretty much the way to go. I have never used reflection before, so I guess I might be missing a thing or two. This is how far I have managed to go:

```
public void addInstruction(String instruction, Object... params)
{
    Class<?> the_class = INSTRUCTION_DICTIONARY.get(instruction);
    Constructor<?> the_constructor = the_class.getConstructor(/* ??? */);
    AIInstruction new_instruction = the_constructor.newInstance(params);

    _instruction_queue.add(new_instruction);
}
```

However, that code has basically two problems:

1. I'm not sure what to put in place of the `/* ??? */`. I guess I should be putting the types of the parameters, but they could be anything, since every `AIInstruction` subclass has very different constructors (in types and amount of parameters).
2. I'm not sure either if the `newInstance` call will work, because the params array contains instances of type `Object`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Class.getConstructors()` to get an array of all constructors in the class. Assuming you only have one constructor, you can simply check for size to prevent OOB Exceptions, and save [0] as your Constructor.

It doesn't look like you need to know what type of parameters that constructor takes, but if you do you can always use `Constructor.getParameterTypes()`. This could also be used to identify between, as stated before, multiple constructors if that were to be the case.